# issue in installing selenium-server-standale

Tags: selenium

I am using  selenium-server-standale-2.32.0.jar and when I wanted to install, it said port 4444 (default port) is busy. I added this to my local host:

```
 http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html
```

and now it is working. Now my problem is that when I want to configure the nodes by this command:

```
 java -jar selenium-server-standale-2.32.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/  wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html/grid/register -maxSession 5 -port 5555
```

It says: INFO - couldn't register this node : hub down or not responding.

Do you know what to do ?

Thanks

Comment: There's a space in your hub definition, is that just a paste issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Those are my 2 batch files (paste on different .bat files):

**HUB**

@echo off

echo --- Starting Grid 2 HUB ...

call java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role hub

**WINDOWS NODE**

@echo off

echo --- Starting Grid 2 NODE ...

call java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role wd -hub http://{LOCALHOST OR HUB IP}:4444/grid/register -maxSessions 1

Run both and it should be work at least on firefox.

Hope it helps